# Difference in values between numpy.correlate and numpy.corrcoef?

Tags: python, numpy, correlation, cross-correlation

It was my understanding that `numpy.correlate` and `numpy.corrcoef` should yield the same result for aligned normalized vectors. Two immediate cases to the contrary:

```
from math import isclose as near
import numpy as np


def normalizedCrossCorrelation(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    normalized_a = [aa / np.linalg.norm(a) for aa in a]
    normalized_b = [bb / np.linalg.norm(b) for bb in b]
    return np.correlate(normalized_a, normalized_b)[0]


def test_normalizedCrossCorrelationOfSimilarVectorsRegression0():
    v0 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, -2, -1, 0]
    v1 = [1, 1.9, 2.8, 2, 1.1, 0, -2.2, -0.9, 0.2]
    assert near(normalizedCrossCorrelation(v0, v1), 0.9969260391224474)
    print(f"{np.corrcoef(v0, v1)=}")
    assert near(normalizedCrossCorrelation(v0, v1), np.corrcoef(v0, v1)[0, 1])


def test_normalizedCrossCorrelationOfSimilarVectorsRegression1():
    v0 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, -2, -1, 0]
    v1 = [0.8, 1.9, 2.5, 2.1, 1.2, -0.3, -2.4, -1.4, 0.4]
    assert near(normalizedCrossCorrelation(v0, v1), 0.9809817769512982)
    print(f"{np.corrcoef(v0, v1)=}")
    assert near(normalizedCrossCorrelation(v0, v1), np.corrcoef(v0, v1)[0, 1])
```

Pytest output:

```
E       assert False
E        +  where False = near(0.9969260391224474, 0.9963146417122921)
E        +    where 0.9969260391224474 = normalizedCrossCorrelation([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, ...], [1, 1.9, 2.8, 2, 1.1, 0, ...])


E       assert False
E        +  where False = near(0.9809817769512982, 0.9826738919606931)
E        +    where 0.9809817769512982 = normalizedCrossCorrelation([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, ...], [0.8, 1.9, 2.5, 2.1, 1.2, -0.3, ...])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your formula with `np.correlate` is wrong, it does not yield the correlation coefficient.

Consider the first example

```
v0 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, -2, -1, 0]
v1 = [1, 1.9, 2.8, 2, 1.1, 0, -2.2, -0.9, 0.2]


np.correlate(v0 / np.linalg.norm(v0), v1 / np.linalg.norm(v1))[0] # 0.9969260391224474
# you can also use
#    np.correlate(v0 , v1 , mode='valid') / np.linalg.norm(v0) / np.linalg.norm(v1)
# but you get same number
np.corrcoef(v0, v1)[0][1]                                         # 0.9963146417122921
```

The correct answer, computed without using floating point should be 59 Sqrt[5/17534] which approximates to `0.99631464171229218403`, which is surprasingly identical to `np.corrcoef`.

Take into account that

```
np.correlate(a, b)
```

when `a` and `b` are 1d array of the same size, returns the scalar product (e.g. `np.dot(a, b)`). The covariance can be computed (even if it is not recomended) as `E[v0 v1] - E[v0]E[v1]`. This can be done as

```
(np.correlate(v0 , v1 , mode='valid') / len(v0) - np.mean(v0) * np.mean(v1))[0]
```

this is equal to `np.cov(v0, v1, ddof=0)[0][1]`. So you can compute the correlation as

```
((np.correlate(v0 , v1 , mode='valid') / len(v0) - np.mean(v0) * np.mean(v1)) / np.std(v0) / np.std(v1))[0]
```

By the way, just use `np.corrcoef` or `np.cov`.

### Math explaination

Your formula using `np.correlate` is equivalent to:

```
E[v0 * v1] / sqrt( E[v0 ** 2] E[v1 ** 2] )
```

where `E` is the sample mean. But the correlation coefficient can be computed as

```
(E[v0 * v1] - (E[v0] * E[v1])) / sqrt( (E[v0 ** 2] - E[v0] ** 2) *  (E[v1 ** 2] - E[v1] ** 2 )
```

Comment: I don't think I follow.

Comment: @user2183336: your math is wrong, you are not computing the same thing